# Why string can be assigned to Array<string>

Tags: typescript

I have following definitions

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
};

interface IMockHelprConf {
    clientPolicys: DeepPartial<IExchangeSettings>;
}

declare interface IExchangeSettings {
    localPolicy: ILocalPolicys;
    signature: ISignatures;
}

declare interface ILocalPolicys {
    maxFileSize?: number;
    filePattern?: string[];
    reciverPattern?: string[];
}

function test(conf: IMockHelperConf){
    ...
}
```

I can now call the function `test(conf)` with following object:

```
test({
      clientPolicys: {
           localPolicy: {
               reciverPattern: '@test.de$'
           }
       }
}
```

this does not result in an error. But I actualy should use `['@test.de$']`. Otherwise running over the "array" actually list the singel characters.

My first thoght was that a string implements `string[]`, but a cast from string to `string[]` using `as` fails with: `Type 'string' cannot be converted to type 'string[]`.

So I would expect that the method call is also not posible with the wrong type.

[Playground sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20DeepPartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20DeepPartial%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IMockHelprConf%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clientPolicys%3A%20DeepPartial%3CIExchangeSettings%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20interface%20IExchangeSettings%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20localPolicy%3A%20ILocalPolicys%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20interface%20ILocalPolicys%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20maxFileSize%3F%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filePattern%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reciverPattern%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(conf%3A%20IMockHelprConf)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%20%20...%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atest(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clientPolicys%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20localPolicy%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reciverPattern%3A%20'test'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atest(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clientPolicys%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20localPolicy%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20reciverPattern%3A%20%5B'test'%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%20%3D%20''%20as%20string%5B%5D%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `reciverPattern` is `DeepPartial<string[]>`. This means that `reciverPattern` has no mandatory properties, it can have any of the properties of `string[]` but it is not required to do so. Since you assign a string to it, the string is compatible, if you would have assigned an object literal, you would have received an error as object literals are checked for extra properties, but string literals are not.

What you want can be achieved in Typescript 2.8 unsing conditional types(unreleased at the time of writing but will be released in March 2018, you can get it via `npm install -g typescript@next`). The idea is to only use deep partial for other objects, not for basic types or arrays:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: 
            T[P] extends Array<any> ? T[P] :
            T[P] extends object ? DeepPartial<T[P]> : T[P];
};
// OK
test({
    clientPolicys: {
         localPolicy: {
             reciverPattern: [""]
         }
     }
})
// Error
test({
    clientPolicys: {
        localPolicy: {
            reciverPattern: "" // error
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, luckylie this shoulden't take long untill released :)

Comment: @lokimidgard yes, that is why I mentioned it, it's very very close ;)